# How to find SPNAME in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-files, netapp

Trying to access files from Azure Netapps via REST API by following documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-netapp-files/azure-netapp-files-develop-with-rest-api
with POSTMAN rest client.

To get **appId, password, tenant** by executing following command in Azure CLI

*az ad sp create-for-rbac --name $YOURSPNAMEGOESHERE --role Contributor --scopes /subscriptions/{subscription-id}*

Here what is **$YOURSPNAMEGOESHERE**?  How to fins this value? I am currently using trail account on Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **note** that, the command you are currently using is related to creating service principal and assigning role to it.

In this **$YOURSPNAMEGOESHERE** , you have to pass the **name of the service principal** you want to create.

Instead of that, you can also give the name directly in string format like below:

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment like below and got the below results:***

```bash
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "TestSP" --role Contributor --scopes /subscriptions/subscriptionId
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[az ad sp | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create-for-rbac-examples)